# HTML form getElementById() is NULL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, null

**Disclaimer**: After some research online, I did attempt something to make sure the DOM was loaded before I queried, so please check that below, maybe I didn't get it right and that's where the problem comes from.
*I know similar questions have already been asked maaaaanyyyy times but my code still doesn't work as I hoped after reading similar responses and trying to adapt my code accordingly, so please help if you can!*

I am currently struggling with a form in my website. I wanted to create a form so that the admin could display a message on some of the site's pages. When I wanted to get the text that I put in the form, the returned value was NULL. I then noticed that the form I had just created was in fact nested inside another form, which doesn't work. I tried bypassing the problem by deleting the sub-form and using a *formaction* field but I keep having a NULL return value.
(I am using **Spip** for my website).

Here is the base HTML code of the admin part of the website, which contains the first form

```
<form method="post" action="#ENV{action}" id="form1">
    <div>
    #ACTION_FORMULAIRE{#ENV{action}}
    
    [(#REM) ------------------------ Alert Message ------------------------ ]
    <INCLURE{fond=formulaires/configure_alert_message}>
    <script>
        var msg_al = document.getElementById('alert_ortho').value;
        console.log(msg_al);</script>  <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE TEXT THAT I WANT-->

    <p class="buttons">
        [(#ENV{choix}|=={valider_seul}|non)
        <input type="submit" class="submit over" title="global_update" value="global_update" />
        <input type="reset" class="submit" title="global_delete" value="global_delete" />
        ]
        <input type="submit" class="submit" title="global_update" value="global_update" />
    </p>

    </div>
</form>
```

Then, here is *configure_alert_message.html*. I want the message to be sent to my page *edit_article/html*.

```
    <div>
        <label for="name">Alert Message :</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="alert_ortho" name="alert_message">Blablabla.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit" formaction="/edit_article.html" form="form1">Save alert message</button>
    </div>
    <p></p>
```

Lastly, here is the part of my *edit_article.html* file which calls for the previous code (this code is also inside a form field, I don't know if that could be a problem). I added the jQuery ready() in it in order to make sure that my query happens after DOM is loaded:

```
        <div style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border: 3px solid #A0A0A0; text-align: center;background: #FFFF00;"> 
            <span style="color:#FF0000;"> <strong> 
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // do stuff when DOM is ready
                    var msg_al = document.getElementById('alert_ortho').value;
                    console.log(msg_al); <!-- THIS RETURNS "Cannot read property 'value' of null"-->
                }); </script>
            </strong> </span> </div>
        <p class='buttons'><input type='submit' name="save" class='submit' value='save_button' /></p>
```

**Why do I, when I try to get my message through *document.getElementById('alert_ortho')*, keep getting null on my page? I thought by using *formaction* and *ready()* before my query I wouldn't have this problem any more. Did I do it wrong for the DOM?**

Thank you!

Comment: (edit: this is wrong, look at @Quentin's answer) To get the text inside, you may want to use .textContent instead of .value

Comment: @AlvieMahmud — It's a textarea. `value` is correct. `textContent` would give the default value which is unlikely to be desired.

Comment: null means it doesn't exist. there's no other explanation.

Comment: actually I am incorrect, look at @Quentin's answer and see why it is coming across as null

Comment: The same question was already asked and deleted here: [HTML form getElementById() is NULL](/q/68083280/4642212). You could’ve edited the original so it could be reopened.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I did edit my former post first, however for the following hour none of the stats changed on the post so I decided to delete and open another (and it helped me get more insight, thanks to Quentin's answer)

Comment: TBH Getting a closed question re-opened is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) searches the DOM of the **current document** for an element with a given ID.

It won't find an element in a **different HTML document**.

When you submit a form the data in it will be passed in the request body (for a POST form) or the query string of the URL. You need to read it from there.

Note that client-side JS has no access to the request body so this will require server-side code.